# Using Entity Framework design time with Postgresql

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, npgsql

I am following this guide to make Entity Framework work with PostgreSQL

https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/wiki/Visual-Studio-Design-Time-Support---DDEX-Provider

When I press next after choosing my connection string the wizards simply breaks and nothing happens

I followed all steps so far and I am using Visual Studio 2013 Community (should be same as Pro version?)

Anyone succeeded in this setup and manual?

Answer (score 0):

Is your project AnyCPU or X64, then try with x86 - see https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2506